# Property does not exist on type String error

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to send a bug report via API, and have an authentication token in my apps metadata settings, which works usually. I refactored that logic out of my main.js and into it's own class, but now I'm receiving 403 errors, which I can only imagine is due to how I'm referencing the token.

```
  class Logger {

   constructor(settings) {
   // getting the settings here and assigning it to the constructor variable
     this.settings = settings;
   }
   static async logInfo(data = {}) {
     console.log('Hello!')
     const url = 'https://sampleUrl'
       const response = await fetch(url, {
       method: 'POST',
       headers: {
         "X-TrackerToken": `${metadata.settings.pivotal_token}`,
         "Content-Type": "application/json"
       },
       body: JSON.stringify(data)
     });
     return response.json();
   }
 }

 const metadata = {
   settings: ''
 }
 const logger = new Logger(metadata.settings);
```

How I call the Logger class in Main.js

```
Logger.logInfo(metadata.settings, bugInfo).then(console.log('print'))
      })
```

On mouse hover the tooltip returns the message 'Property does not exist on type String error.', before the move into it's own class I referenced it with the same syntax, so not sure how to proceed here.

Comment: Mouse hover over what? And how are you using `logger`? And what property?

Comment: @Amadan When I hover over .pivotal_token, updated with how I use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the `settings` with the constructor, so you need to use this `setting` in the `Logger` class, but you are using another variable for `X-TrackerToken` that is not defined.

```
const metaData = {
  settings: ""
}

metadata.settings.pivotal_token // ---> undefined
```

You are trying to get `pivotal_token` from the settings which is a string and obviously, there is no `pivotal_token` method existing for your `settings` strings.

Comment: @novomino thanks for your answer, I'm still somewhat confused. I've updated with how I call the logger class. I'm just not sure what your saying the path forward is, as I reference my token settings the same as I always have.

Comment: no worries @cbln . take a look at `X-TrackerToken` method inside your Logger class, you passed `metadata.settings.pivotal_token` the problem is with this part, your metaData object has no property with name of `pivotal_token`

Comment: take a look at `Logger.logInfo(metadata.settings, bugInfo)` and think about what is the `pivotal_token` right now? @cbln

Comment: @novomino This is where I'm not following, if it refs my metadata settings, my token is in an object structured as { "name":"pivotal_token",  "type":"text", .... }. Therefore it should hit it as before no? I'm sure this is obvious and somehow flying over my head

Comment: you need to pass the token data for `X-TrackerToken` but you didn't pass it, you passed a undefined value to it @cbln

Comment: @novomino I understand now! Thanks for the explanation, obvious in hindsight. But does this mean that I have to hardcode the token into the metadata const, rather than interpolate it from my metadata/manifest.json file?

Comment: it's my pleasure @cbln . about your question, no need to hardcoding. just pass a correct object to your Logger constructor (an object with the token data). if you can't figure out how to get that object (with the token) from your codes, as the last solution you can hardcode it.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing metadta.settings.pivotal_token but metadta.settings is a string.
It's not having any pivotal_token property.